# Compiler error in newer version of gcc

Tags: c++

Following code compiles fine with g++ 4.4.5 but reports error with g++ 4.5.3 . Is it the compiler behavior that has changed. If so, what got changed?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
  public:
        A() {}
};

int main()
{
  new A::A();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the error with us?

Comment: why `new A::A()` and not just `new A()`?

Comment: test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:12:7: error: expected type-specifier
test.cpp:12:7: error: expected ';'

Comment: `code`test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:12:7: error: expected type-specifier
test.cpp:12:7: error: expected ';'

Comment: This is an extract from a old code which does not compile anymore. I can change it to use A() but I am trying to find out what got changed

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously the compiler behavior has changed, since you have an error where you had none before.

The thing is, calls to constructors should not be qualified (ie, preceded with a type). It seems that gcc 4.5.3 used to ignore the issue whilst 4.5.5 is stricter in its enforcement of the Standard.

**EDIT:**

I seem to remember this was forbidden (but everyone let it slide) in C++98. The C++11 Standard however explicitly accepts it, at least in certain places (see §5.5.1/8). It may well be that a bug was introduced when improving the support for C++11 in gcc or on the contrary that now it is only allowed in those places the C++11 Standard accepts; at the very least gcc 4.8.0 [still rejects the code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/Frd02%246).

Strangely enough, Clang 3.2, which is generally strict, accepts the code without a warning.

Comment: Any idea when it got changed? Is it mentioned in gcc release notes? Any reference would be helpful

Comment: @user2270465: sorry, it does not seem mentioned; interestingly it seems Clang 3.2 accepts the code without a warning... And it seems explicitly allowed in C++11 §5.5.1/8 [...] *Where class-name::class-name is used and the two class-names refer to the same class, this notation names a constructor (12.1).*

Answer (score 0):

Although class-name::class-name notation is defined as a constructor, It is not a type-id.
The requirement of *new* specified in the [expr.new] definition in C++11 [5.3.1].

```
new-expression:
   ::optnew new-placementopt **new-type-id** new-initializeropt
   ::optnew new-placementopt( **type-id** ) new-initializeropt
```